# Change Dateformat for Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datetime, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the following datetime picker function in my system  https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/  and the  standard datetimepicker format is `mm/dd/yyyy` how can I change it to `yyyy/mm/dd` or `yyyy/mm/dd`
I tried the following but it failed :

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({

                    format: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
```

Comment: Have you check the moment.js documentation for the right format supported? I believe what you are using is not valid. `yy` for example is not part of the format. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1):

Refer the followoing Link:http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'MM/YY'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OP didn't mention wanting to exclude the days. If anything OP tried format which include the days in it.